# SDK integration with ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an Id scanner and the scanner has some SDK demo that is done using WPF and my custom-made program is done wing ASP.NET MVC 5 and what I want is whenever I scan the ID I want the name from the ID to be passed to my MVC how do I make it happen, is there a way that I can import the SDK into my ASP.NET MVC web app?

Comment: Please don't tag asp.net core for a ASP.NET MVC 5 which is for .Net Framework.

Comment: The  ASP.NET MVC application will be running on the server. The scanner also will be connected to the server? Do you expect the client scan the ID and that is passed to your application?